# Opencart 1.5.1.3 display special price with start and end date on product display page

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am working on Opencart 1.5.1.3

On the product display page, it's displaying the **Active Special Price** and also the **Normal Price** with a line in the middle.

For all special prices available for a product I want to display: **the special price with its start and end date**

I tried my best by changing data in the *tpl* file and also in the module *php* file, but it didn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you the exact code because I don't want to change my own installation, but you would need to change /catalog/model/catalog/product.php and edit line~14 "$query = ..." so that it returns the start and end date to the controller.

Then edit /catalog/controller/product/category.php line~187 and add to the array "$this->data['products'][] = array(" the start and end date information.

You should now be able to access that information and format it however you want in /catlog/view/theme/THEME/template/product/category.tpl

Comment: Rather than changing /catalog/model/catalog/product.php and /catalog/controller/product/category.php why can't we make new functions, i think that would be much batter not to change the original Model.

Comment: Sure, go ahead, a new function is a good idea. I was just pointing out the sections that were applicable. Make sure you remember to change the controller to use the new function.