# Opencart 1.5.1.3 redirect to Home page after login

Tags: php, opencart

I am working on Opencart 1.5.1.3.

After logging in I am automatically taken to the My Account Page:

```
index.php?route=account/account
```

I want it to go to the Home page instead:

```
index.php?route=common/home
```

Is this possible from the admin panel? If not what code would I need to modify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open

```
catalog/controller/account/login.php
```

Find

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
```

replace with

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link('common/home'));
```

Comment: can you please see and give me same help for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015765/opencart-1-5-1-3-display-special-prrice-with-start-date-and-end-date-at-product